# Exit a resize event

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues exiting a resize event. I have some operations i want to do whenever the browser window is being resized. However after the resizing event has finished i have some further code that i wan't to be executed. Due to the resizing event not finishing the code that exceeds this event are not being executed.

Is there a way to finalize the event or should the resizing event be implemented in another way? How do i get doMoreStuff() to be executed after the resizing?

Code example:

```
$(window).resize(function (){
    doStuff();
});

doMoreStuff();
```

Comment: Can't you call doMoreStuff from doStuff?

Comment: Hi. I can but i dont want to call all further implementation from the event. I want the event to finnish.

Comment: See the second option in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

1. Inside the resize eventhandler, after your other code:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  doStuff();
  doMoreStuff();
});
```

2. If you want it to be asynchron (so the eventhandler can finish):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  doStuff();
  settimeout(function() {
    doMoreStuff();
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: It's because you have to prefix code snippets which come between list items with `<!-- language: lang-xxx -->` tags. You can see the changes I made if you try to edit the question now.

Comment: Your answer works. I've added location.reload(); in the setTimeout callback function. This enables the desired functionality of the page after a resizing event has occurred.